# Extract pattern from string with regex

Tags: php, regex

How can I extract the number and key from the following strings using regular expressions?

```
 Duplicate entry '24040446669881344' for key 'clave_something'
 Duplicate entry '24040446669881345' for key 'clave_something_else'
```

I tried using substrings but it wont work when the length of the chain changes.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With this, you will get all integers from string:

```php
preg_match_all('~\d+~', $string, $match);
print_r($match);
```

<kbd>**[demo](https://eval.in/380289)**</kbd>

For you specific example, to extract also the key:

```php
preg_match("~'(.+?)'.+'(.+?)'~", $string, $match);
print_r($match);
```

<kbd>**[demo](https://eval.in/380293)**</kbd>

or if you wish to fetch multiline string:

```php
preg_match_all("~'(.+?)'.+'(.+?)'~m", $string, $match, PREG_SET_ORDER);
print_r($match);
```

<kbd>**[demo](https://eval.in/380296)**</kbd>

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
preg_match("/Duplicate entry '([^']+)' for key '([^']+)'/", $theString, $matches);
```

The variable `$matches` will contain your desired data.